# One to Many Form in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, one-to-many

I have a form a manager fills out for each employee once a week as an audit. Currently the form is in Excel. They would like this data to be tracked over time to review for trends. What they are asking for is basically a one to many relationship. Each answer on the form should create a new record in the table rather than one record per audit form. There are 34 audit questions which can result in either yes, no or n/a. Most of my experience is in SQL and Oracle databases so I am not very familiar with Access. They are looking for a form in Access they can input the audit response and then I can create trends and so forth in Tableau. 
So for example Rep: Ms. Smith Date of audit: 09/10/2016 then each of the 34 questions with a year or no response. I cannot seem to manage to get the form working without having to enter the reps name 34 times. Any recommendations for an Access newbie?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood your question, but here is what I would do.

You can create 2 tables, one called `Representative`, the other `Audit`.

In the table `Representative`, create a field `Rep_Name` and let Access create an AutoNumber primary key.

In the table `Audit`, create a field Date/Time for the date of the audit, create a Number field `Rep_ID`, 34 Yes/No fields for your Audit questions and let Access create an Autonumber primary key.

Then in *Database Relationships*, link your `Representative`>`ID` with `Audit`>`Rep_ID`.

You can then create 2 forms, one where the User select/enters his name, and a second form where the date is entered/pre-filled and the questions will be asked. You can link both forms using a button.